# Oracle RMAN Back-up files in red hat can be read in windows?

Tags: oracle, backup, rman

We have performed a cold back-up of a database using Oracle RMAN. The back-up ran on a Red Hat Server and then the files were copied to a mounted external hard-drive. Can this back-up files then be read in a windows PC or there will be some file system compatibility issue? When restoring the back-up with RMAN, does the hdd needs to be mounted in a linux server or it can be any server?

Comment: I think you're in luck because you have the same endian on both because it's actually the same hardware architecture. I believe you still need to look at the `rman convert` command though.

Answer (score 1):

RMAN can be used for cross-platform tasks but you cannot restore your classic full backup from Linux to Windows

Comment: Nice, thanks! When connecting this hdd to a windows pc for verification, will be possible to view this file?

Comment: if you want to open Linux HDD on Windows machine you can do it using one of the methods in this URL http://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/

Answer (score 0):

[This Oracle document](https://blogs.oracle.com/AlejandroVargas/resource/Database-Migration-Windows-Linux-with-RMAN.pdf) describes how to do a Windows->Linux migration.

You'll need to follow the same approach, but swap the source and target architectures. Obviously you'll have to create the Oracle DB service on Windows too.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'll pass it forward to the team

Answer (score -1):

You can read the files with a hex editor, but you can't restore Oracle data files backed up from a Linux server to a Windows server. The endian is different. Depending on how your database is setup you can use data pump with transportable table spaces to migrate an Oracle database from Linux to Windows.

[Transporting Tablespaces Between Databases](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17120/tspaces013.htm)

Comment: The endianness is exactly the same, assuming he means Redhat on Intel.

Comment: Right I must have been thinking about Unix. The file system are still different, hence transportable table spaces.

Comment: The file systems are different. The endianness, ie: the order of bits in a byte (little endian vs big endian) is little endian in an Intel CPU - windows and x86/x64 Redhat both run on little endian Intel/AMD CPUs. SPARC (so, Solaris) and PowerPC (AIX) are Big Endian IIRC. You're correct about the use of TTS, but I don't think you understand what endianness is :)